# What is the origin and/or earliest use of the Ushpizin prayer (invitation of the 'exalted guests') during Sukkot?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, sukkot, hachnasat-orchim-guests, arizal

While reading about Sukkot[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkot) I came across a mention of a prayer recited during Sukkot, during which a celebrant invites the seven 'exalted guests' (well-known heroes and leaders of the Hebrew people/religion) into his home before a meal eaten in the *sukkah*. According to the Wikipedia article, this originates with Isaac Luria's Kabbalah tradition, and I haven't found any other references to this prayer/ceremony that he called *ushpizin* (Aramaic for 'guests') elsewhere.

My question is, is there any earlier form of such a tradition predating Lurianic Kabbalah? If not, when was this first openly used by the Jewish community?

Answer (score 5):

[Jewish Chronicle](https://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/ushpizin-1.5457) states

> **Apparently, the earliest source for the custom of welcoming the
>   Ushpizin on Succot is in the Zohar, the classic of Kabbalah.** The Zohar
>   makes clear that a central reason is to stress the importance of
>   inviting guests to share the holiday with us: "One must also gladden
>   the poor, and the portion [that would otherwise have been set aside
>   for these Ushpizin guests] should go to the poor. For if a person sits
>   in the shadow of faith and invites those guests and does not give
>   their portion [to the poor], they all remain distant from him" ([Zohar
>   III 103b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.103b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

R Isaac Luria lived from 1534-1572. The [Zohar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zohar) is much more ancient.

Comment: Is there any evidence of this practice between the writing of the Zohar and, say, 1300 CE? And when "was this first openly used by the Jewish community?" Before or after the Arizal?

Comment: One way to test this would be to look at ancient mahzorim for Soukot if someone has the time and inclination

Comment: Does the Zohar specify Succot or all holidays?

Comment: So are you saying that the Zohar might have been hinting that general hospitality to people relates to hospitality to spirits? If so, this  kinda mirrors the Christian 'entertaining angels' concept.

Comment: @DanF yes there is an explicit reference to the Souka

Comment: @UriahBlacke no there is a general concept of hospitality to guests on Jewish holidays, e.g., Rambam's [Shvitat Yom Tov 6:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Rest_on_a_Holiday.6.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): "While eating and drinking, one must feed the stranger, the orphan, the widow, and other poor unfortunates. Anyone, however, who locks the doors of his courtyard and eats and drinks along with his wife and children, without giving anything to eat and drink to the poor and the desperate, does not observe a religious celebration but indulges in the celebration of his stomach."